# Altium designer: Lock all selected PCB object

Tags: altium

How do I lock all selected objects on a PCB in Altium Designer?

I know about find similar objects but if I need to lock the objects that I've selected manually with the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PCB Inspector (bottom right -> PCB -> PCB inspector)

Answer (score 1):

PCB Inspector or PCB List. Both should work. Personally I find the PCB List easier to navigate, but it really depends on what you're looking to change.